# How to get node name and values from an xml variable in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following xml -

```
<Surveys xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ImmForm XML Schema NHS Direct.xsd"><Svy SurveyName="WeeklyFluSurveillance2012/13-NHSDirectWeek40w/e07/10/2012" OrgCode="NHS Direct"><TotCR>222.10</TotCR><PerCF>0.40</PerCF><PerCFunder1>0.20</PerCFunder1><PerCF1to4>0.30</PerCF1to4><PerCF5to14>0.50</PerCF5to14><PerCF15to44>0.40</PerCF15to44><PerCF45to64>0.20</PerCF45to64><PerCF65plus>3.60</PerCF65plus>
<PerCFNE>4.22</PerCFNE>
<PerCFNW>6.50</PerCFNW>
<PerCFYH>0.80</PerCFYH>
<PerCFEM>1.00</PerCFEM>
<PerCFWM>1.50</PerCFWM></Svy></Surveys>
```

I need to select the child node name and its value in a resultset with 2 columns (FieldName, FieldValue) like -

```
TotCR   222.10
PerCF     0.40
...
PerCFWM   1.50
```

The nodes in the xml will vary and may not always be same. Even the values may be integer or text.

Can you guys please suggest how to do this using OPENXML in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `local-name()` function to the get name of the XML node - try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML =  '...your xml here.....'

SELECT
    NodeName = C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeValue = C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @input.nodes('/Surveys/Svy/*') AS T(C)
```

This should give you an output something like:

[image]