# Dynamically Get XML data type Values in different Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have table with having one column with xml data type and contains values in xml format.

e.g.

```
<row><A>1</A><B>xyz</B></row>
<row><A>2</A><B>jkl</B></row>
```

And want output in table:

```
-------------
|  A  |  B  |
-------------
|  1  | xyz |
|  2  | jkl |
-------------
```

I want to show ouptup like this dynamically. Is there any function which returns xml data to table?

Comment: What do you mean you want to show it dynamically? What's dynamic about what you need?

Comment: T-SQL hates dynamic result sets (in general; this is not restricted to XML). You can use the XML methods (`.nodes`, `.query`, `.value`) to get any part of the XML you please, but not in the form of dynamic columns (either in name or in type), while `OPENXML` wants a schema or else it returns a generic table. If you know your data looks exactly like this, you can write a query to turn it into a rowset. Otherwise, you either need to get ugly with dynamic SQL or just leave it to the client.

Comment: @Larnu  - All columns should get dynamically without specifying columns name, typ

Comment: That isn't how SQL works, @vinGa . That's like expecting the put the command "`MyTable`" and expecting SQL Server to know that you  want to `SELECT` all columns from it, along with any related rows which can be found by a foreign key. *You* **need** to tell SQL Server how you expect to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can check and try this query.

```
declare @X xml = '<row><A>1</A><B>xyz</B></row><row><A>2</A><B>jkl</B></row>';

select  x.r.value('(A)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [A],
    x.r.value('(B)[1]', 'varchar(500)') as [B]
from    @X.nodes('/row') as x(r);
```

Here is the output:

```
A   B
-------
1   xyz
2   jkl
```

You can find the [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8825329353e27b428504e1191cbe5e3f).
To access the node name and their values dynamically you can try the following query.

```
DECLARE @input XML =  '<row><A>1</A><B>xyz</B></row><row><A>2</A><B>jkl</B></row>'

SELECT
    NodeName = C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeValue = C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @input.nodes('/row/*') AS T(C)
```

It will give output as shown below. To know more you can refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999582/10532500).

```
NodeName    NodeValue
--------------------
A           1
B           xyz
A           2
B           jkl
```

Comment: Here you are giving column names,type.  I don't want to give it, because actual table has more columns

Comment: @vinGa You need to either provide the name or the index of the node to access the name values.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be nothing dynamic about what you want, and you just need to use XQUERY:

```
SELECT V.YourXML.value('(/row/A/text())[1]','int') AS A,
       V.YourXML.value('(/row/B/text())[1]','varchar(3)') AS B
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,'<row><A>1</A><B>xyz</B></row>')),
            (CONVERT(xml,'<row><A>2</A><B>jkl</B></row>')))V(YourXML);
```